# How are these Row ID's Being Generated

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, encryption

I'm trying to figure out how a primary key is being generated at the application level (ISV I don't have the code base) so I can do consistent inserts on the back end without worrying about dup keys.

Ordered by ID just to give an idea of the progression:

### EDIT

Date Created with Corresponding ID

Beginning:

```
date         sysid              c_time
02/10/2009  A00029BC75ECF751    1835010
02/10/2009  A00059BC76712863    1835013
02/10/2009  A00069BC7BF6F327    1835014
08/14/2013  A0006A235AF21680    5841653
02/10/2009  A00099BC76D57865    1835017
07/06/2009  A000A9C590BDF134    4000288
02/10/2009  A000B9BC73594306    1835019
08/19/2009  A000D9C857013579    4795995
02/10/2009  A000E9BC7222D209    1835022
04/08/2009  A000E9C0007D0727    4810168
```

...

Ending

```
date         sysid              c_time
10/06/2010  AFFFA9E2205D9752    5919265
01/29/2013  AFFFCA1706413272    3420395
02/10/2009  AFFFD9BC75264250    1835005
07/13/2009  AFFFD9C60B25C732    4402146
11/09/2012  AFFFDA11FBC8C706    5908518
07/17/2009  AFFFE9C64E1EB645    540642
09/30/2010  AFFFE9E1C7021704    3264751
02/10/2009  AFFFF9BC755DE457    1835008
```

I'm thinking that this is some some algorithm on the datetime with A as a prefix ?

Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Well i'm 100% positive the ID is not generated at the database level (I read through all the stored procs, functione etc ...).  If it does make a difference it is MS-SQL as a varchar(16) field

Comment: Do you want to know the method that generates this ids or any method that generates such id's?

Comment: Do you have (or can you get) a creation date to go with each of those record IDs? Treated as Windows *tick* values (100-nanosecond increments), those values (if you mask off the `0xA0` part) cover a span of approximately 59 years. Do you know if new keys are always larger than any previous key?

Comment: @VikramBhat Yes I would like to reverse engineer the method that generates the ID's

Comment: @JimMischel I edited the question to include the Date and Time (Not sure how that time is being converted.   However there doesn't seem to be a clear correlation

Comment: I suspect that it's generating sequential IDs and then obfuscating them. Like what YouTube does with their video IDs. There are several ways to do that. Eric Lippert shows how with a [multiplicative inverse](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/). Another possibility is that they're using an XOR and shift technique. See [Obfuscating sequential keys](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=839) for an example. Either one can be reverse engineered, provided you have enough time.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna The id might be random as well because there are ways to generate random keys without any duplicates

Comment: @JimMischel That Obfuscating sequential keys linke is great !  If you want to write this as an answer I would like to mark it as such.  I think i've figured out a way to get it to work using the article, thanks.

Comment: @VikramBhat After fooling around with the ID's and sequencing I believe they are in fact Obfuscated Sequential's with the A used as record type identifier.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna But didnt get point of you so interested in how they are generated ? Do you need an algorithm to generate them yourself?

Comment: @VikramBhat Figuring that out would be ideal and is what I am trying to do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out how a primary key is being generated ... so I can do consistent inserts on the back end without worrying dup keys.

Well, it's impossible without the algorithm or source code, but a timestamp seems reasonable since the *numeric* difference between sequential IDs is the same order of magnitude between the top and bottom sets.

Since they look like 64-bit hex numbers you *could* just add 1 to the "highest" number.  There's no guarantee, however, that the 3rd party app is also checking for duplicates - it may insert a value that collides with one that you enter.

Assuming that their inserts are sequential (and your inserts don't need to be sequential) you could start at `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` and work backwards.

There's still variables that you need to consider - are the first 3/4 bits (1010 = A) flags?  Will inserting a value with a 1 in the second bit do any harm?  None of those questions can be answered just by looking at the generated IDs.

Anything you try, though, should be validated with the ISV.

Comment: 64-bit hex numbers, not 128.

Comment: @DStanley Unfortunately the third party vendor is useless for the scale that business has took the application too.  And the company is invested in the platform enough that they don't want to move to a tailored application.   However I need to figure out some kind of viable solution

Comment: @Jim - you're right - I was counting _characters_, not _bytes_.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna There is no solution that's guaranteed to be 100% viable without knowing the constraints that the application has.